# Evaluate class separability

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, data-visualization

I want to evaluate separability of my features for 3 classes and do the same for other 2 sets of features and eventually show that my features provide the best separability. To make it clearer, I want to measure for far the different classes are as well as how compact every class is. I found scatter matrices are a good option for these.

My questions are:

1. Can they be used when the data is not linearly separable/when the distribution of the data is unknown or not gaussian (somewhere I read that scatter matrices are useful when the data is linearly separable or gaussianly distributed).
2. This will just give me numbers, does there exist a graphical way to illustrate the separability. My features are 256-D, and there are 409 data instances.

Comment: For graphical illustration, try t-SNE, which is a popular modern way to reflect high-dimensional structure in 2D

Answer (score 0):

In order to assess how far the clusters are, you may do a simple test: compute mean points of every cluster and look at the distances between these points.  This will not tell you if the data is separable, or how scattered the data points are inside the cluster, but it will give you some indication of what is going on.

Regarding the scatter matrix, which is an approximation of the covariance matrix:
Covariance matrix (usually you would look at its eigenvalues/vectors) describes the set of data points.  The question you would ask here are: ok, what are the directions that maximize the variance of the data and thus carry most energy.  It doesn't care if the data is linearly separable or what is the distribution of the data.

I don't think there's a nice way of picturing data in 256 dimensions!  But you can graph margins and the like.

Hope this helps,
Alex